# How do I send multiple emails based on values selected from various drop down boxes in infopath?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

How do I send emails based off a selections made from multiple drop down boxes?

As I have three drop down boxes and assuming 3 different values are selected, how do I have 3 seperate emails sent based on the values selected ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean 3 separate emails then you'll need to create 3 email connections pulling their TO: information from different fields.

If you mean send an email to 3 recipients, you could use a concat(MyField,.) rule on each dropdown to append its email to an EmailTo field.

We use that kind of concat method to enable quick entry of multiple text phrases on mobile devices. [See a description and sample form here.](https://formotus.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201042397-How-to-build-an-alternative-to-a-Combo-Box-)